# VBA Code For Export Excel Range and Format shapes in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an array to format Powerpoint slides using Excel VBA code as shown below. I need help formatting each individual slide shape via my code. Currently my VBA code copies a range of data and pastes it into Powerpoint.

```
 Sub PasteMultipleSlides()

 Dim myPresentation As Object
 Dim mySlide As Object
 Dim PowerPointApp As Object
 Dim shp As Object
 Dim MySlideArray As Variant
 Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
 Dim x As Long
 'create a new non contagiuos range
 Dim newRng As Range

 Set range1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$6:$I$8")
 Set range2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$17:$I$33")

 Set newRng = Union(range1, range2)



 'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
 On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then Exit
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not open, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
   If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
   End If

   On Error GoTo 0

   'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
   PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

  'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

  'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
   MySlideArray = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

   'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
   MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"), 
  Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$8,$A$17:$I$33"), _
  Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"), Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"), 
  Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"))

   'Loop through Array data
 For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
'Copy Excel Range
 With MyRangeArray(x)
   'hide all rows
   .Parent.Rows.Hidden = True
   'show range's rows
   .EntireRow.Hidden = False
   .Copy
   'Paste to PowerPoint and position
   On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = 
   myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2) 
   'Excel 2007-2010
    Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'Excel 2013
   On Error GoTo 0
    'show back all rows
  .Parent.Rows.Hidden = False
End With
'Center Object
  With myPresentation.PageSetup
    shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
    shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)
  End With

  Next x

 'Transfer Complete
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  MsgBox "Complete!"

  End Sub
```

The issue is that the size for all the slides are coming out the same size as the first. How do I format the sizes of each shape?

Comment: Use the properties `.Left` and `.Top` to set the location on the powerpoint slide and use `.Width` and `.Height` to set the size of the shape object? You can get the individual shape objects by using the `Shapes` collection with an index on each slide.